# Asset return series turned into data.frame

Tags: r, time-series

I have an asset return series (see below), which is of class 'numeric' and structure type named num, with the names the corresponding time-stamps. I wish to perform the *applying.rolling* on the series.

I understand that I need to transform my asset return series (EURUSD15_ccret) into a timeseries (data frame, xts, zoo object). Could anybody help on this? Tried a couple of methods I found online but never managed..

```
             

> str(EURUSD15_ccret)
 Named num [1:40948] 0.00 7.22e-05 0.00 7.21e-05 0.00 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:40948] "3/11/2014 22:05" "3/11/2014 22:10" "3/11/2014 22:15" "3/11/2014 22:20" ...
> class(EURUSD15_ccret)
[1] "numeric"
> tail(EURUSD15_ccret)
9/23/2014 15:00 9/23/2014 15:05 9/23/2014 15:10 9/23/2014 15:15 9/23/2014 15:20 9/23/2014 15:25 
   3.880632e-04    7.759457e-05   -3.880331e-04   -1.552554e-04    3.104867e-04    0.000000e+00
```

Comment: its a function in the PerformanceAnalytics package..sorry should have been more clear about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using apply.rolling is non-standard, use rollapply, which is part of zoo.

```
require(xts)
EURUSDx <- xts(EURUSD15_ccret, order.by=as.POSIXct(names(EURUSD15_ccret),
                                                   format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
rollapply(xsample, FUN=mean, width=5)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this, but I get an error message: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Ok will do, sorry for late reply - was away from the office

Comment: Thank you - got it to work... midday tiredness wasn't helping yday!

Comment: You're welcome.Just to let you know, if someone posts an answer which works, you should upvote it and click the tick next to it to close it. That way other people who find the question know it works, and other potential solvers know it's completed. Cheers.

Comment: @Lister: tried that, but apparently I need a higher reputation! But will remember form now forth and maybe I get to answer a couple myself! Have a gr8 weekend!

Comment: Cheers @Philipp, I forgot about the restriction on upvotes. Still, while you can't upvote yet, you can accept answers. If you hover to the left of the arrows on my answer, there should be an unchecked "tick". Ta.